# How to reference a Fody MethodDecorator in another project?

Tags: c#, logging, fody, compile-time-weaving

I'm trying to use the [Fody MethodDecorator](https://github.com/Fody/MethodDecorator) to log method entry/exit in multiple projects. I've created a project in visual studio and implemented the *IMethodDecorator* interface as described in the [ReadMe.md in the Fody MethodDecorator project](https://github.com/Fody/MethodDecorator/blob/master/readme.md).

The Fody MethodDecorator works fine in the one project where I've implemented the *IMethodDecorator* interface and I can log method entries/exits. But when I try to log method entry/exits in other projects by adding a reference to my first project, there is no logging in any other projects.

[I've created a github repository with a minimal working example just to show the issue, click here for link.](https://github.com/FluffyBike/ConsoleApp1)

There are others that have had the same issue, [like this post from 3 yeas ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648179/how-to-use-methoddecorator-fody-decorator-in-another-project). But the solution in that post is to add the Fody and MethodDecorator nuget packages to all projects. I have already added both nuget packages to all projects. I have also added the *FodyWeavers.xml* to all projects.

If you want to know what my code looks like, [just check out the git repo.](https://github.com/FluffyBike/ConsoleApp1) Is there anything else I have to do to get logging of method entry/exit working in other projects?

I would like to simply add a reference to my first project and reuse the method decorator from the first project. I'm using .Net 4.8, Fody 6.5.3 and MethodDecorator.Fody 1.1.1.

**Edit**
If you download the repository and get the error: *A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(MsBuildMajorVersion)" that evaluates ...* This is apparantly due to a bug in Visual Studio, [that can be overcome by a restart.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57261146/a-numeric-comparison-was-attmepted-on-msbuildversion-that-evaluates-to-i)

Answer (score 1):

For Fody.MethodDecorator to work in other projects, you need to add the module
`[module: Interceptor]` in each project.

My suggestion is to create an Interface as below in each project, and make sure your classes inherit from the interface. ( This way you only added the module at one place in the project)

```
[module: Interceptor]


public interface IInterceptor
{
    // no methods here.
    // the interface is used only to register the Interceptor attribute at the module level.
}

public class SomeClass : IInterceptor
{
    [Interceptor]
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to the question, but I ended up switching to [MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody](https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody).
It's a nuget package that does the same thing as *MethodDecorator.Fody*, and has an interface that you implement in an almost identical manner.

I got MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody to work in multiple projects, by referencing an attribute that I only created in one of the projects. You still have to add the nuget packages [MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody) and [Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fody/), and also add the FodyWeavers.xml file to each project though.